# Whats the correct way to maintain ConnectionMultiplexer object in StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, redislabs

I'm are storing `ConnectionMultiplexer` static object in ASP.NET MVC website getting ~500req/sec which are hitting Redis instance on RedisLabs. Once in a while I see errors saying `SocketFailure on EVAL` and increased connection count on RedisLabs dashboard. Should I have  dispose old `ConnectionMultiplexer` instance  and recreate new or try reconnect manually after those exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system should attempt to reconnect automatically. What it does *not* do is retry your commands, because it has no way of knowing what did and did not complete at the server (because: the socket failed; for all it knows, the "ok" response could have already been sent by redis).

So, you should not need to dispose/reconnect. You can monitor the connection failure/reconnect via events published on the multiplexer instance. You can also use the `.IsConnected()` method  on a database (this takes a key for server targeting reasons, but if you are only talking to one server, you could pass anything as the key).

Comment: Thanks for a fast answer. And what about those increased connections count? I'm running 5 asp.net instances and normally seeing 10 connections, but after SocketFailure error connection count increases to +70? What worries me is that ConnectionMultiplexer is opening new connection and leaves hanging old ones.

Comment: @paul that is curious; is there any way I can repro?

Comment: We'd be happy to help in any way - let me/support@redislabs.com know if you need us :)